# Unbelievable reputation for a new member

Tags: support, reputation

I've just looked at the stats for a relatively new member and cannot believe the rep he supposedly made in one day, being a relative rookie. https://stackoverflow.com/users/2125720/jayram?tab=reputation

Can this accumulation of rep for June 11 be explained? Was there something going on in the back end?

I posted a comment on one of his [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100839/list-all-rows-that-contain-certain-text/17101066?noredirect=1#comment24742863_17101066), which contained only links, advising that he should summarize the solution in the post, as per SO best practice. He replied with a very cocky "Sure ..." -  Where/How did he get that many reputation in one day? Hard to believe it's not a system error.

Comment: Low rep != rookie, just because a person has not active in the site before doesn't mean they're not an expert.

Comment: I meant "rookie" simply in terms of tenure on this network. I never meant to dispute the poster's expertise. It would be great if there were a general reference framework for these terms. Unfortunately there isn't. So I picked the first term that came to my mind. Shoot me.

Comment: I'm not a programmer nor a developer and I have 5k rep; earned it in 3  months.

Comment: nothing suspicious about it! If you are a regular visitor of SO, you will quite often see similar things there.

Comment: I see a lot of warning comments from other users on this fellow's answers, and I've just found one that was plagiarized from another SO answer. I think there _is_ something to look into here, although strictly the rep gain is just "answer a lot of questions, you'll get some upvotes".

Comment: Blatant serial upvoting reversed yesterday for this user - so yes, the activity on this member's account is suspicious

Comment: Thanks for chiming in, brettdj. How is such activity possible? Is there a way to round up folks for points passing? I don't like to think that people try to gain rep with unorthodox measures at SO. I'm too new and too innocent to even know what might be done. But if it can be stopped by scrutiny and moderation, please put that person on the list. -- Kia ora.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On June 11, he earned 200 reputations from upvotes/downvotes, 30 from accepted answer and 100 from association bonus. So 200+30+100 = 330.

Answer (score 11):

The user got their association bonus that day - the rest is from upvotes + accepted answers, so not all that unbelievable.

Looks like the OP also answered as many questions as they could, garnering any reputation thay could. Possibly in order to get the association bonus.

As for that answer - the question is a bad question and should be closed and deleted.

Comment: The question is NOT a bad question. It is a perfectly viable scenario for Excel. It should NOT be closed. If anything, migrate it to SU, but don't close it just because you don't understand the scope.

Comment: It is a bad question @teylyn. In fact, there hardly is a question.

Comment: I disagree. The scope of the question is a perfect Excel scenario. It just does not belong on SO. It would not be flagged as inappropriate at SU. Just migrate it and all will be fine.

Comment: @teylyn - "I need to create a query" is not a good question. The OP has shown 0 effort and has not specified the end result.

Comment: OK, split hairs. The title may not be worded appropriately, but it's a valid question. At SU this would have been asked and answered, repped and up-voted, question and answer.

Comment: Then flag it @teylyn.

Comment: @Bart, I have flagged numerous questions for migration to SU, only to find them getting closed at SO instead, without migration. That is frustrating. The Qs were not worded badly, perfect fits for SU, but still sit in SO as closed. That does not help anyone. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184398/what-has-precedence-close-or-migrate

Comment: @teylyn - Migrations by moderators will not happen if the receiving site moderators will not accept them.